# error while installing meteorite packages

Tags: linux, node.js, meteor

I have installed meteorite using command- sudo -H npm install -g meteorite 
but when i am trying to install the iron router package i get the following error.

> mrt add iron-router

Done installing smart packages

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Object # has no method 'handlePackageServerConnectionError'
    at _updateServerPackageData (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:221:10)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:201:15
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:240:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:238:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:229:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:228:19)
    at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:200:16)
    at _.extend._refresh (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:181:40)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:147:14
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:323:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:316:34
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:314:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:300:26)
    at _.extend.refresh (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:143:18)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-packages.js:63:22
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-packages.js:52:11
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:240:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:238:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:229:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:228:19)
    at exports.doOrDie (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-packages.js:51:31)
    at refreshOfficialCatalogOrDie (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-packages.js:62:3)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands-packages.js:1891:3)
    at /home/kvg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.ra1aiw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1241:23

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/command.js:41
            throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
                                                      ^
Command exited with 8/null

I am getting the same error while trying to add spin also

> mrt add spin

Comment: if you're following discover meteor book, upgrade to new one,propbaly you're following the old book before 0.8 version

Comment: No I am using the latest version of meteor 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `meteor add iron:router`

Since v.1.x, I think,you have to use `meteor add` command for package install

Comment: The method you have suggested is working the same as -                      mrt add iron router.                                                                                            The real problem is arising after this stage-                                      Done installing smart packages
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[                    ] 9% 21.4s     Updating package catalog